# How to change the monitor's refresh rate?

Tags: monitor, 11.10

How do I change the monitor's refresh rate in Oneiric?

There is no option to do it in the Displays dialog now. By default it's 60Hz, but I need 75Hz on my monitor.

In previous releases there used to be such an option in the Displays dialog.

**Edit - Half baked solution**

The best I could do so far was:

```
xrandr -s 1280x1024 -r 75
```

This is perfect, but my problem is that it isn't permanent. It defaults back to 60 Hz after logging out and back in.

Perhaps this should go into some script and added to startup? I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Open `Startup Applications`, and add that command

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So my solution is, which seems to work well on my system:

1. I opened up *Startup Applications*
2. I clicked *Add*
3. I typed a name and the following in the command field:

   xrandr -s 1280x1024 -r 75

Using this *xrandr -s 1280x1024 -r 75* is run at every sytem startup and sets the refresh rate as required. There could be a better option but right now this seems to be OK for me.

Hopefully the LTS will fix the showstopper bug of no easy, gui way to change the refresh rate.

Comment: actually, this does *not* run on system startup, but rather on (your) user login, which is quite different. The initial login screen will not be affected by this

Comment: Also, after screensaver you'll need to run it again.

Comment: `Rate 144.00 Hz not available for this size` even though it is (it says right above when I run just `xrandr`)

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to use `xrandr`. Calculate the needed modelines for your resolution and refresh rate:

`cvt 1600 900 75`

(Here my example resolution is 1600x900.) Now create a new mode with `xrandr`:

`xrandr --newmode "1600x900_75.00"  104.00  1600 -hsync +vsync`

Add the new mode to `xrandr`:

`xrandr --verbose --addmode VGA-0  "1600x900_75.00"`

and activate it

`xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "1600x900_75.00"`

Note that your values will be different. In particular, your monitor might not be VGA. Run the `xrandr` command with no arguments to find out the name of your monitor and use that instead. Running `xrandr -q` will display a list of available outputs.

[Here's some more information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) on xrandr.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is not working as I expected `pratik@pratik-SVE15116ENB:~$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_75.00"  104.00  1600 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: failed to parse '1368x768_75.00' as a mode specification
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
`

Comment: how do you get the `--newmode` numbers from the `cvt` command? in other words, where does the `104.00` come from?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, once I did `xrandr --addmode`, the new refresh rate appeared in the GNOME settings. No need to activate it with `xrandr`. @golimar, the `cvt` command generated all the `xrandr --newmode` parameters. See the [Arch Wiki on xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions) for details and example output.

Answer (score 10):

In 12.04 you can change the refresh rate by modifying the rate tag in ~/.config/monitors.xml after you configure your monitor(s). This works on reboot for me.

Example:

```
<monitors version="1">
    <configuration>
        <clone>no</clone>
        <output name="DVI-I-0"></output>
        <output name="DVI-I-1">
            <vendor>ACI</vendor>
            <product>0x24e1</product>
            <serial>0x01010101</serial>
            <width>1920</width>
            <height>1080</height>
            <rate>144</rate>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>0</y>
            <rotation>normal</rotation>
            <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
            <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
            <primary>yes</primary>
        </output>
        <output name="HDMI-0"></output>
        <output name="DP-0"></output>
        <output name="DVI-D-0">
            <vendor>DEL</vendor>
            <product>0xa017</product>
            <serial>0x31314553</serial>
        </output>
        <output name="DP-1"></output>
    </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Comment: After hours of searching this was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm, it says `144.00076293945312` in `<rate>`, but it's clearly not

Answer (score 6):

The refresh rate for a monitor is automatically detected by Compiz.

If you wish to change it,  install `compiz-settings-manager` you can do that with the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Find in the dash "ccsm" and click the composite plugin.

Untick "detect refresh rate" and adjust the refresh rate to your manual setting.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the daily build, ran it live and I did what you suggested. When I was done I hit the Back button, but nothing happened. I logged out and back in, but no change. Do I need to restart the computer at this stage?

Comment: hmmm - I have my doubts that you can do this via a live CD.

Comment: I don't see how I should apply this setting. I uncheck the box, set the refresh rate to 75 Hz and all I can hit is the Back button at the bottom left. When I come back, it's 50 Hz again.

Comment: Are you now using an installed version - or still running a live CD?

Comment: This answer is not working as I expected .It shows Refresh rate for OUR SATISFACTION, but after i reboot , setting is reset to 60HZ

Comment: there are no options for refresh rate in compizconfig-settings-manager any longer