# blurry screen and fonts after installation

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon

The problem is my screen is not as sharp as I would like, the fonts are greyish and the whole thing is quite literally giving me a headache when I have been looking at it for a while.

My machine has an i5 processor and ATI Radeon 6470 graphics card. I have tried changing resolution but that does not help.  The screen looks like the really old crap monitors that my previous employer had.

I have checked this out and can see there is a known problem.
When I was sorting out Ubuntu I pressed the button for the additional driver and on `settings/systeminfo/graphics` shows `Vesa Seymour`.

Can someone please tell me (in very easy step by step language!) how I can fix this.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi Allan, many thanks for posting your question.  I am using newest version 11, 64 bit.  My friend has been helping me today and it appears that the Graphics card is working ok.  The screen still hurts my eyes however compared to the screen using windows.  I would be grateful of any comments in relation to this.  Have tried adjusting the contrast etc on the Catalyst box now too.  Maybe it;s just me !!!??!!

Comment: What is the refresh rate of the monitor?

Comment: Its 60hz and it wont let me change it ..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59621/how-to-change-the-monitors-refresh-rate

Comment: 60hz and I cannot change it .. VLC does not play films either I have just discovered .. !!

Comment: This is what you are looking for I hope tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

I have an nVidia 8600 GT graphics card and I just updated to Ubuntu 12.04. I suffered the same issue with Gnome as well as Unity after upgrade from 11 to 12.

The solution was to change refresh rate, it was at 75Hz and I lowered it to 60Hz. The image got sharper and stopped making my head hurt.

Comment: Can you include how you changed the refresh rate?