# How to see/change screen refresh rate or monitor frequency?

Tags: 12.04, screen, monitor

My eyes hurt so I thought I should check the screen refresh rate (monitor frequency), but I couldn't find it.

Where is it? (in Ubuntu 12)

Comment: If your eyes hurt, I suggest you check out the topic of color temperature correction (F.lux and redshift are two great apps for this)

Comment: For me Unity seems to be the problem. I have an HDMI Y connector (two inputs, one output, you can choose which one to pass through), which I confirmed by a few tests: 1) I plugged another computer with the same driver/OS into the same thing and it flickered. 2) I lowered the resolution and it reduced the flicker but didn't remove it 3) I plugged my computer into the same thing with a USB-C to HDMI cable and it continued flickering 4) I plugged my computer directly with the USB-C to HDMI cable into the monitor and it continued flickering, although slightly reduced. 5) Mirroring doesn't flicker.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Compiz looked like it worked. But it didn't work.

So the solution to this is the following.

```
First we check available modes.
$ xrandr
1440x900       59.9+*   75.0
1280x1024      75.0     60.0

Then we pick the mode, including resolution and refresh rate.
$ xrandr -s 1440x900 -r 75

Or just the refresh rate
$ xrandr -r 75

Let's see if it worked
$ xrandr
1440x900       59.9+    75.0*
1280x1024      75.0     60.0
```

Alright. Then all you have to do is add the command to Startup Applications and be done.

Comment: I wonder why didnt some one mention this ?????? Rate 75.0 Hz not available for this size" . Its not the correct solution at all.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Try using a different type of cable, for example HDMI.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi You probably used xrandr -r 75.0, which may not work, while xrand -r 75 should.  Even if the displayed framerate is something like 74.98 (my case) you should take the nominal value and use xrandr -r 75.

Comment: Could somebody please tell me why GUI tools ignore refresh rate? If xrandr can do it, why can't they? Isn't it it a basic setting?

Comment: BTW, [from here](https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html): star (*) is the current mode, the plus (+) is the preferred one. Most monitors report a preferred mode to the driver.

Comment: I recently needed to use the xrandr command as follows: `xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.93` for this to work, otherwise there was no change.  Check the output device from the 2nd line of `xrandr` output.  Would be nice if there was a way without adjusting xorg.conf or adding a startup script to make this permanent.  Somehow 60.01 (= the default rate) makes my eyes bleed (screen flickers in the dark areas), whilst using 59.93 doesn't (recent HP Probook).

Comment: @4levels That worked. Here is [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554559/xrandr-message-rate-144-0-hz-not-available-for-this-size) with that solution.

Answer (score 16):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

then type **compiz in your unity dash** , it will list you **compiz settings manager** .**Open compiz and at general options click at composite and there you have untick the detect refresh rate then you can manually set the value you want** . [image] .

and two know allowed refresh rates for the resolution you can use `xrandr`

the second row are allowed refresh rates with respect to the resolutions . so by depending on resolutions you have set ,  you can change the refresh rate by using the above methods  . 
[image]

Comment: How can I know which is the max allowed? Can't this break my monitor?

Comment: Do you really think its that simple ??? It adjusts to 60Hz on reboot no matter what value you set !!!

Comment: WARNING: Starting compiz broke my system and forced me to reboot