# CRT as 2nd monitor goes screwy after start up?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, radeon

new install of 12.04 on an  old dell with a radeon ATI RV516 video card with monitor out and s-video out.

During boot up all is good. Both screens operate and look fine.  Then just before the desktop appears, the CRT goes purple and is converted into heavy horizontal lines, but as i said during boot up it was fine and the resolution was fine.  The main monitor, an lcd, operates normally.

everything else works fine, it's just the picture on the CRT that is screwed up.

I used the same monitor and CRT running 11.10 which worked fine

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos_edit?ns=1&video_id=zfuh6lBMLnc) is a vid showing the completely normal screens at reboot then the purple badness when the desktop loads??   and don't laugh at the slow machine, it's old.

CRT is a Toshiba 32MW7DB, s-video is a direct input.  My xrandr data has no data in the second column for the s-video (apologies for not knowing how to present the data as it appears in the terminal window)

```
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
S-video connected 1024x768+1680+282 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       59.9* 
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
DVI-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Comment: update the video link to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfuh6lBMLnc

Answer (score 0):

Check your display settings.  You may need to tell Xorg (It manages displays) what refresh rate your CRT needs.

Try different options for your second monitor, notably the refresh rate.  CRTs, if I recall correctly, don't like the same rate as LCDs.

Comment: when i go to system settings-diplays all i can do is change the resolution and that only makes what is a purple mess become a green mess.  How do i change refresh rates please?  What i find confusing is the CRT screen is perfectly fine during boot up.  thank you

Comment: Take a quick look at this, it might be helpful:  

http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate    
Also, please edit your question with info on your crt monitor brand and model as well as output from 'xrandr'.  
CTRL+ALT+T, then  
`xrandr`