# Ubuntu screen flickering after laptop repair

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, dell

I own a Dell Vostro 3550 laptop which uses both Windows 7 and Ubuntu. The laptop broke a month ago and I called Dell support to fix it. A small metallic clip was dislodged from the back lid and short-circuited  "something" on the motherboard. I wasn't present during repair so I do not know exactly what was roasted.

After repair everything works fine on Windows 7 but on Ubuntu the mouse cursor and the windows environment are flickering. Sometimes it stops for an hour or so but it reoccurs.

I've tried a fresh install of Ubuntu along with Fedora and Funduntu but flickering is still present. My intuition says that its a hardware issue since I've never had flickering problems in Ubuntu(currently run the 12.04 vostro 3550 distro), although I kind of spended a lot of time in order to setup Vostro 3550 graphics to work properly.

I want to investigate more before calling Dell support again because Windows 7 works flawlessly and it might be a drivers problem(although I've tried almost everything regarding ati drivers for ubuntu, disabled discrete card, disable integrated card etc.)

The graphics card are  AMD Radeon 6630M and Intel HD 3000.

Any ideas on how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this sounds a lot like a hardware issue to me.

One thing you might want to try is adjusting your OS's monitor/display settings, on the off-chance that it has selected a default resolution or refresh rate that is not compatible with the display.

Comment: What is your guess about the fact that on Windows 7 it works fine but on Ubuntu flickering exists?

Comment: I've tried this solution http://askubuntu.com/a/155351/187872 and it seems that it works for now. Also the dual monitor display work fine now. Only once when I booted from Ubuntu the login screen couldnt be displayed and I had to log in through command line and reboot. I will use current setup for some weeks and if the problem is solver i will mark the thread as "solved"!

Comment: Well the aforementioned solution doesn't work at all. Don't know why after I first tried it the flickering stopped but now it is still present and more intense. If its a hardeare issue it's is kind of weird that on Windows 7 everything works fine..