# Ubuntu 12.04 white stripes on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, display, screen

[image: T410s with white stripes]My dual monitor settings worked perfectly fine until just recently. Now the resolution on the second monitor is very low and it shows white vertical stripes. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME 3.4.
I am using a docking station for my Thinkpad T410s, that is how the Laptop is connected. The main monitor (which works well) is connected via DVI. The laptop monitor works well wenn not attached to the dual screen system.  If I turn off the main monitor via software, the laptop monitor still shows white stripes.

Here is my `xrandr -q`:

```
  Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3360 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
  LVDS1 connected 1440x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 190mm
   1440x900       60.1*+   59.9     49.3  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Have you tried with a different DE, like Xfce?

Comment: `xrandr` output seems ok. Seems stupid but --- have you tried changing the cable? (average HDMI cables and connectors, are, well, average...)

Comment: Hm, added more details to describe the setup.

Comment: @Sina Please post a complete hardware description

Comment: And maybe a photo of the second screen during this set up?

Comment: What other information do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If enable dual head mode (two X screens), the second monitor went white after login with unity or unity-2d. After tracking the gnome-session, it is caused by running "nautilus -n" for this configuration. And if kill the nautilus process, the desktop showed up normally on second screen. It is a Bug. Try using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Could you explain how I can reproduce "killing nautilus" just to see if this is really the cause? I killed Nautilus but nothing happened.

Comment: I ran 13.10 from USB stick and indeed the issue was not there any more. So I guess thats the sad solution.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the LCD panel OR the video card are bad, or it could just be a bad driver.  Head to the manufacturer's website, download, install and reboot.

Below are some thing to check:

- Try connecting to an external monitor, if the line appears on the
  external monitor, the issue is a bad video card.  If the issue does
  NOT appear on the external monitor, the issue is the LCD panel.
- It might be a simple fix like a loose connection to your laptop
  display.
- Could be the cable on the hinge side that is getting worn.

Comment: External monitor works fine. Since I am using a docking station there is not much I can do in terms of cable or loose connection.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change refresh rate (mainly decrease it) which seems to be the real problem. For instance [check this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate) to see how to change the refresh rate

Try different refresh rate until you got the optimal vision. And for your screen I think it's enough a 1366x768 resolution with a refresh rate of 60

```
xrandr -s 1360x768 -r 60
```

Comment: I have the Intel VGA. No Nvidia hardware installed. I tried: `sudo xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 59.9` But it did not change anything. If I typed `xrandr` again still the same. What am I missing.

Comment: @Sina Try this xrandr -s 1360x768 -r 60 or this xrandr -s 1360x768 -r 59.8

Comment: You mean `xrandr --output LVDS1 -s 1360x768 -r 59.8`, right? Both command work without error but nothing happens. If I do not include `--output` it cant find the display. The original screen resolution is 1440x900 by the way.

Comment: @Sina yes of course I mean it

Comment: it seems a hardware problem! try ubuntu live cd and disconnect your external display to see if it works

Comment: Thanks, using a Live CD was a great idea. Somehow didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

The timings are wrong for the laptop display.  That looks an awful lot like what happens when it's trying to use the same resolution on two monitors, but one of the monitors is not capable of that resolution.

Try decreasing (or just changing) the resolution on the laptop monitor.

Comment: Tried that. Thats not the issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Just to be clear, the resolution *and* refresh rate when it works are both exactly the same when it doesn't work?

Comment: It does not work. Whatever I do changing the resolution.