# How do I enable 60hz on my 4k monitor?

Tags: ati, monitor, fglrx

I have the very new Asus PB287Q 4K monitor and I've enabled display port 1.2 in its OSD menu system, but my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop still isn't using 3840x2160 at 60hz - it's stuck at 30hz.  I'm curious what's the correct way to get this to 60hz?

I have an ATI Mobility FireGL M8900 and I'm using fglrx.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M]

fglrx:
  Installed: 2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

Here is the relevant xrandr output:

---

```
DFP5 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
3840x2160      30.0*+
2048x1536      30.0
```

Comment: do you have a crossfire?

Comment: No, this is an M6600 Dell Precision laptop with the M5950 FireGL card.

Comment: What are you not gwtting 60herts in. Desktop? Or an application like a game?

Comment: Like, at the X level.. I can see the modeline in use with xrandr and it's 30hz

Comment: I said 5950 above and I realize that was wrong.. I meant M8900.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency

Comment: Are you sure you aren't connected via HDMI rather than display port? Specs from http://www.asus.com/Monitors_Projectors/PB287Q/specifications/ True Resolution : 3840x2160 at 60Hz (DisplayPort) ,3840x2160 at 30Hz (HDMI)

Comment: I am sure I'm connected via display port.  I don't have a cable in my laptop's HDMI port at all.  I'm using a direct display port to display port cable from my laptop to the monitor.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to check http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency ...

I pasted the top output of xrandr in my question - the 60hz modeline isn't being reported by the monitor (even though there are numerous reports of people successfully getting this monitor to work at 60hz on windows)

Comment: Perhaps you can verify that your monitor works at 60 Hz on another system. This would make it clear whether the problem was with the monitor or the system.

Comment: My monitor works at 60hz on the same laptop in windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Research indicates that for the Dell Precision M6600 laptop you may need the latest linux beta driver

Available here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx (version 14.6 at this moment. Supports 12.04.4 and 14.04)

I realize this isn't a canonical answer but it may be helpful in your situation.

I believe that this answer already covers the vast majority of this type of question: [How to see/change screen refresh rate or monitor frequency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency)

If this doesn't work I would contact Dell to discuss your [warranty status](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/warranty).

Comment: I have the Dell M6600 with the ATI Mobility FireGL graphics card, not the nVidia/optimus/quadro one.

It's also worth noting that I'm using display port just fine with the monitor now, it's just running at 30hz instead of 60hz.

Comment: What's the BIOS version?

Comment: I have the A12 bios currently, but I could try upgrading.  Checking the release notes of the A13, A14, and A15 updates there is nothing that mentions my graphics card or anything else which I would think would apply here, though.

Comment: Added link to Dell warranty status page.