# Xrandr message: Rate 144.0 Hz not available for this size

Tags: nvidia, xrandr

When I type `xrandr` and press enter, the output I get says that I have 144.0 hz available to use on my 1920x1080 resolution, but when I try the command:

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 144.0
```

or `144` without `.0` I get the message:

> Rate 144.0 Hz not available for this size

I get that message with every possible refresh rate, even the current using refresh rate (60 Hz). I have `nvidia-settings` installed which also handles the refresh rate, might the problem be there?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with my 144hz monitor. You might try using a full set of parameters. For example, to get my 2560x1440 screen to operate at 144hz, I had to do the following:

1. Run `xrandr` to find the name of your connected display output. In this case, DP-0 is my connected DisplayPort:

   ```
   $ xrandr
   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
   DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DP-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+ 144.00   120.00    99.95    84.98    23.97  
   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```
2. Then use the `xrandr` command again with the `--output`, `--mode`, and `--rate` parameters. For my 2560x1440 monitor, I specified the following:

   ```
   $ xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 144.00
   ```

The monitor blinks and switches to the new rate. I'm not sure how to properly use the `-s` parameter.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! It worked for me only after specifying the proper `--output`. I guess `xrandr` was targeting the first output in the list or something (while my screen is connected in the second one).

Comment: This is till working on 18.04.