# increase screen refresh rate for external monitor?

Tags: 14.04, external-monitor

My external monitor display is "wavy" or "wobbly".  A colleague looked at my screen and told me that this is probably bad for my eyes.  Will increasing the refresh rate fix this problem?  How do I do this in ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: What is(are) the native refresh rate(s) of your monitor?  (It might be that decreasing will solve your problem)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency

Answer (score 6):

You have to use Terminal. Open it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then run `xrandr`.

You might get something like:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm

N°:0   1024x768   60.0     87.0*
N°:1   1024x576   60.0
N°:2   960x600    60.0
N°:3   960x540    60.0
N°:4   800x600    85.0     75.0     72.0     60.0     56.0
```

Then you can choose from the resolutions and refresh rates listed above. The following line of code changes to 1024x768 at 60Hz:

```
xrandr -s 0 -r 60
```

Where `-s` will change your resolution to the the one specified in the number zero and `-r` will change your refresh rate to 60Hz.