# How do I set my refresh rate to 120/144 hz in Gnome 3?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg

I realize there are several questions that look very much like this one, but none of their accepted solutions work.

For example, I can set the refresh rate to 144hz using `xrandr`, but the obvious issue is that the change is reverted on reboot. I have added it to a startup script, but even then the changes are reverted any time my PC wakes up from suspend, or even when my monitor goes to sleep ([`dpms`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling))

I have tried setting ***and saving*** the refresh rate using `nvidia-settings`, which successfully modifies `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "2560x1440_144 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then rebooted, but Gnome 3 either doesn't care about that, or overrides the refresh rate to 60hz. Also `gdm` (the Display Manager) sets the refresh rate to 60.

I have also seen some people suggest changing the frame rate to 144 in `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml`. The file contained information about all the monitors I've ever plugged into my PC, so the first thing I did was delete it and reboot. After applying a setting in "Displays" the file was recreated with one monitor configured at the frame rate 59.95. I changed the frame rate to `143.96` (I got the number from `xrandr`), saved the file and rebooted. Both `gdm` and Gnome 3 ignores it and keeps setting my monitor to 60hz.

In the end I have found no way of setting my monitor's refresh rate to 144hz in a stable and acceptable manner when using Gnome 3. Can it even be done?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567478/eye-strain-how-to-change-refresh-rate-to-120-hz?rq=1 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300569