# Dual monitors (60 hz and 144 hz) games can only run in 144 hz if I unplug the 60hz monitor

Tags: unity, 15.10, display, games

On my Ubuntu 15.10 system I have two monitors powered by one Nvidia Geforce 660 ti: a 60 Hz monitor connected via DVI and a 144 Hz one connected via Display Port.

Using nVidia or `xrandr`, I set my monitors refresh rate to 144 Hz. But I only get true 144 Hz in games (in this case CSGO) if I completely unplug the 60 Hz monitor before starting CSGO.

Could it be that Unity uses the lower refresh rate when both displays are plugged in? I can verify that the monitor is running in 144 Hz via the monitors info menu (as opposed to not setting it via xrandr), but it still feels not like 144 Hz.

Using Google I could not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Ubuntu but with the hardware itself. I could infer that you're running on non-identical output ports (1 HDMI and 1 DP or 1 VGA and 1 HDMI...) on one graphics adapter (Before the comment and subsequent edit).

If you want true independent refresh rates, you will need either one the following:

1. An additional graphics card to run the existing monitor
2. A replacement monitor that runs at 140 Hz on the existing graphics card.

Comment: You are correct. The slower monitor is connected via DVI while the 144 hz display is connected via Display Port on one Nvidia Geforce 660 ti. So you are saying if I connect both displays via DVI I should get independent refresh rates?

Comment: Edited answer to clarify...  Don't forget to  click the little grey ☑ at the left of this text if that finally answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with it, but if you use vsync for the 60hz monitor it seems to also cap the 144hz monitor. You might need to disable it but might cause tearing on the 60hz monitor.

Good luck!

Comment: How can I disable vsync? I am not sure it is turned on at all in unity. I tried to set Sync to VBlank in the nvidia settings: nvidia-settings --load-config-only --assign="SyncToVBlank=0"
I can confirm it is set to off via the graphical settings UI. This did however not change anything. Thanks!

Comment: You can change the settings by start the nvidia-settings using `gksu nvidia-settings`. I think it then might just be the hardware.

Comment: You might also want to check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567478/eye-strain-how-to-change-refresh-rate-to-120-hz?rq=1