# 15.04: Launching some programs turns monitor off and on (like for a resolution change)

Tags: ati, resolution, 15.04, monitor, display-resolution

I just upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 and one of the first things I noticed is that the monitor often behaves like it was changing the resolution (a click sound from inside the monitor, black screen, another click, screen is as it was before).

One cause for this I can reproduce is starting some specific programs (qTox, Unity system settings, PokerTH, run `inxi` from terminal), but it already happened on more occasions. Also happens at least five times while it initializes the desktop session (after login screen).

Relevant system specifications:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV535 [Radeon X1650 PRO]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@85.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV530 GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.5.2
```

on a [Belinea 10 60 75 CRT-monitor](http://www.cnet.com/products/belinea-10-60-75-crt-monitor-19/specs/).

When this happens, there are no messages appearing in the `dmesg` output.

Anybody knows what the reason could be and how to fix it?
Do you need more detailed information or command outputs?

---

**Update:**

Trying different resolutions I found out that the monitor's native resolution (1600x1200, 75Hz) does not change the problematic behavior at all, while switching to the lower 1024x786, 75Hz, the screen still goes black for a second in the same situations as before, but there are no two clicking sounds any more as if the resolution was going to change. Just a short time of black. However, I can not work with this resolution on that big screen...

Comment: How old is the video card pushing the display?

Comment: I am not sure, it's a second hand computer. Less than 10 years, I assume. But I doubt it could be a physical defect, as it is not triggered randomly but whenever I launch some specific programs. And it did not happen on Win7 or on 14.10 before the upgrade.

Comment: What graphic driver are you using ? Out of idea, you could try to switch driver from [ATI proprietary to open source radeon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx), or vice-versa.

Comment: @solsTiCe As you can see in the `inxi -G`-output in my question, I use the default open-source `radeon` driver, not the proprietary `fglrx`. And I was not able to switch, because it seems like the current version of `fglrx` does not support my card model any more. Or can you point me to a working installation guide for older cards?

Comment: What happens if you boost the resolution to the native 1600 x 1200 at 75 Hz that your CRT supports? Are the results the same?

Comment: Try if less resolution would help, normally most programs are Compiler due to resolution with 1024x768(798) Pixels ?!

Comment: @ElderGeek I tried your suggestion, but the flashing when I start some programs persists... Btw: How can I set the frequency? I can only chose from a small set of resolutions in the Control Center, but no option for the frequency.

Comment: @dschinn1001 I also tried this, but I can't use this setting on that monitor. It looks just huge and pixelized, no space for nothing. However, the clicking sound stopped when I open one of those programs, but the screen still goes black for a second. It just does not try to change the resolution anymore.

Comment: Regarding frequency (aka refresh) see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours and I solved by installing the AMD catalyst center.

I have a different graphics card, but it *should* work well since it is a Radeon series anyway.

I followed this [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)  guide and solved that.

Comment: First, this is not really an answer but more of a comment, as an answer should explain _how_ to do this. Second, I already looked for proprietary drivers for this graphics card, but was not able to find any for 15.04 as the card is pretty outdated... I'm afraid your answer does not help much in my case, but thank you anyway for trying.

Comment: I'm sorry @ByteCommander, but this is all I know and I tried to help you. The guide, anyway, explains fully what you should do.