# external hdmi tv, set as second display, blinking (brakeing signal) randomly

Tags: hdmi

First of all, let me tell you that I am a total beginner regarding Linux. I did a clean install of Lubuntu 20.04 LTS, on my old Asus -x553ma laptop, so no dual boot only lubuntu. My problem is regarding external display (TV) connected via HDMI.

I have one monitor, connected via VGA to the laptop and a TV connected to the laptop via HDMI. The displays are set to “clone” mode. The thing is that the HDMI signal to the TV starts to brake (it is manifesting with the TV screen going black for CCA 2 sec.) The interval of this happening is totally random. Sometimes starts happening right after turning on the TV, and sometimes after half an hour/hour or so. And the frequency of the occurrence is totally random too – sometimes it is often and sometimes scary. I did not manage to find any connections with anything.

Note that I had windows 8.1 before instaling Lubunutu and all was ok. Ok, to be honest, the “flick” would accrue CCA once per 2 weeks.

I bought a new gold plated cable from Delock– all the same.
I “played” with the resolutions and refresh rates after googling – all the same
I set the sound output on “Analog Stereo Output” (via Pulse Audio) hoping that removing the sound from the HDMI data flow would do the trick, but nothing.

I had some issues with the system not remembering the display settings though, which I solved with these instructions:
( [How can you make a .sh file come on at startup in Lubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166777/how-can-you-make-a-sh-file-come-on-at-startup-in-lubuntu-12-04))

After extensive googling, I haven’t found anything helpful. The nearest tip to a helpful one is this:
( [External HDMI monitor blinking after upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812324/external-hdmi-monitor-blinking-after-upgrade-to-16-04) )
*As you can see it is for Ubuntu, which doesn’t have to matter, but the key thing is that I do not have the monitors.xml file to edit, as the tip suggests.

I don’t know what to do, I am desperate, I use the comp. primary for watching movies and stuff on the TV and with the above-mentioned issue it is impossible to watch anything.

I would be very grateful for ANY help.

Comment: Are you trying to power three screens at the same time? (Notebook display + External monitor + TV?) If so, that's way too much work for the integrated graphics chip on your Pentium CPU. Any video with a decent amount of movement would overwhelm the system 

Comment: I set the laptop's screen to off permanetly I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: Does not help too much, but had same problem yesterday.  HDMI TV would flick to black screen for about a second or two.  Today is working good.  Do not know if laptop or TV or connections were the problem.  TV usually goes to blue screen if connection lost, black for power off.

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2457715&highlight=lubuntu+external+tv

Comment: What screen does the TV show when no connection(TV on, but cable unplug or computer off)?  Thinking if they are different, then might be a problem with TV's power.

Comment: the power seems ok, I have other devices connected via hdmi to the tv, and most important - under windows it worked mostly fine, as I said in the question