# Xorg.conf doesn't work

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, 17.04, xorg.conf

I'm trying to save my resolution/refresh rate configuration using the "Save to X Configuration File" option in Nvidia X Server Settings. It generates a xorg.conf file in /etc/X11 directory. Here is the xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 367.35  (buildd@lgw01-18)  Tue Aug  9 10:11:49 UTC 2016

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.66  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Mon May  1 15:45:32 PDT 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics M227WAP"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 61.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 750 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_60_2 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

How we can see in `Section "Screen"`, I have this line:

```
 Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_60_2 +0+0"
```

But every time I reboot my computer (OS: Ubuntu 17.04 LTS), the resolution and the refresh rate is set to "auto". This "_60_2" metamode makes difference to me, then I want to know how can I make it(xorg.conf) work.

Answer (score 0):

As we have chat, sometime prime don't support set refresh rate.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/982558/setting-default-refresh-rate/

You have to set the screen resolution and the avalible refresh rate as per the below article.

[How to see/change screen refresh rate or monitor frequency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency)

Comment: Do I save this ".nvidia-settings-rc" in the same directory of xorg.conf?

Comment: I save .nvidia-setting-rc in home dir and xorg.conf in /etc/X11 dir

Comment: Try not to change the dir that it suggest.

Comment: Ok, I tried it. Unfortunately it did not work. I checked if the hidden file was in the home and if the xorg was in the etc / X11 as described above and configured. When the computer started the refresh rate and resolution was "auto". Thank you for trying.

Comment: goto dash >logs > important tab. Are you getting some error related to nvidia here?

Comment: Yes. I have this: Sep 26 00:44:19 joao-desktop nvidia-settings[3923]: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
Sep 26 00:44:19 joao-desktop nvidia-settings[3923]: PRIME: is it supported? no

Comment: I don't know if is what you're looking for...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66183/discussion-between-aravind-and-joao-victor).