# How to check current monitor frequency?

Tags: monitor, frequency

Can I check my current monitor frequency? Is it use any application or only open a applicaton?

Comment: More `xrandr` options regarding monitor frequency are discussed in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59621/how-to-change-the-monitors-refresh-rate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `xrandr` in Terminal for the **refresh rate** if that's what you want.