# Ubuntu does not change refresh rate , causing Eye strain

Tags: 14.04, compiz, resolution, screen, monitor

I tried **`Every`** solution on AsKuBunTu. The reason why I am asking the question is : `No answer solved my issue`.

I started Ubuntu which causes eye strain(same time spent on Win-7 never caused eye strain).

As per answer topped on google search like [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59621/how-to-change-the-monitors-refresh-rate), [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency) and many more places but no answer worked.

As per `Experts` here , they said following should work `xrandr -s 1366x768 -r 75` , but it gives me message `Rate 75.0 Hz not available for this size` .

Also some `Expert` also gave answer like [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59621/how-to-change-the-monitors-refresh-rate?rq=1) which obviously not working .He says use Compiz using `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` . It sets the refresh rate , but after I reboot , all is gone and set to 60Hz , I dont know was that refresh rate in Compiz just for our satisfaction or what ?

And now please answer genuinely , dont answer like `use Redshift , flux` , as it **`Does Not`** solve the issue , I dont like my screen in Red color.

My Os: `Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahar`.

Please answer if you know , I really dont want my eyes dried , tired , stressed anymore on Ubuntu.

Comment: You have to add a modline - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Comment: @bodhi.zazen , I hope **`YOU CAN READ`** . Can't you read that I tried that solution Too. Can you read in the middle of the question , I got error `Rate 75.0 Hz not available for this size` after checking that question . This is NOT duplicate as that question doesnot solve the issue.Why dont you answer it?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen , sorry dude , I was lil tense as Ubuntu gave me Errors -> `Rate 75.0 Hz not available for this size` ! Comeon ubuntu , this is my lappie , apply it no matter what happens ! :)

Comment: Were you by some chance confused by the [answer?] [1] [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency The very first step is to confirm the refresh rates "modes" available for your monitor. Blindly choosing a rate that isn't compatible with your hardware will never work.

Answer (score 1):

You did not read the links I gave you nor did you post sufficient information for me to answer.

I can take a guess.

You have to manually add a mod line and you will have to modify this answer to match your hardware / xrandr output.

Run cvt

```
cvt 1366 768 75.0
```

notice how the desired refresh rate is added to your resolution ;)

output will look like this:

```
# 1368x768 74.90 Hz (CVT) hsync: 60.30 kHz; pclk: 109.50 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_75.00"  109.50  1368 1448 1592 1816  768 771 781 805 -hsync +vsync
```

Add it to xrandr (without the "Modline" part)

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_75.00"  109.50  1368 1448 1592 1816  768 771 781 805 -hsync +vsync
```

Now here is where you did not post sufficient information, so I can not write an answer.

The output of xrandr shows your display name, mine shows

> eDP connected 1366x768+0+0

so mine is eDP. Yours may be VGA-0 or LVDS or ....

run xrandr with your display name

```
xrandr --addmode eDP 1366x768_75.00
```

NOW run xranrd to set your desired resolution

```
    xrandr --output eDP --mode 1366x768_75.00
```

If you have a problem post the output of xrandr and the commands I gave you exactly as you enter them and any error messages.

Don't forget to ask nice because I am a volunteer.