# How do I set the refresh rate for my CRT monitor to 100Hz and above?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

I am currently using a 21"FD Premium Sun Microsystems monitor. For running of experiment purposes, I would like to set the refresh rate for the monitor to at least 100hz if possible. Any clues out there?

My current graphics card is nVidia Quadro 2200.

Comment: First off, your monitor likely doesn't support that refresh rate, and you'll end up with a non-working setup (best case scenario) or a fried monitor (worst case scenario).

Comment: But for the cause of science, I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrandr` should do the trick nicely.

First, compute your modeline for your resolution and refresh rate:

```
cvt 1600 900 75
```

(Here I'm assuming `1600x900@75Hz`.  Make sure you change that if yours is different.) Then create a new mode with `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_75.00"  104.00  1600 -hsync +vsync
```

Add the new mode to xrandr:

```
xrandr --verbose  --addmode VGA-0  "1600x900_75.00"
```

Then enable it:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "1600x900_75.00"
```

**Note that your values will be different.** Run `xrandr` with no arguments to find out the name of your monitor and use that instead. Running `xrandr -q` will display a list of available outputs.

[Here's some more information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) on xrandr.

Thanks to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/59626/366676) for the nitty gritty details.