# Display unrecognized

Tags: display, display-resolution, external-monitor

I'm using a lg 20EN33 and Ubuntu 16.04lts didn't recognized this display. Because of that, I can't set the display recommended resolution (1600x900) and I'm stuck in 1024x768.

I tried this:  [How to change the monitor's refresh rate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59621/how-to-change-the-monitors-refresh-rate) and using `xrandr` I was able to set the proper resolution (1600x900), but now I see little dots around the monitor and it's really annoying.

I don't know how to look up for this trouble.

**EDIT:**
If I run `lspci -vnn | grep -i vga -A 8` I get the following output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:3977]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Did you install graphic drivers?

Comment: I haven't, the Additional drivers option show me "Unknown:Unknown, this device is using an alternative driver."

Comment: Could you add to question the output of this command: `lspci -vnn | grep -i vga -A 8`?

Comment: @Danibix done :)!

Answer (score 1):

**Please, take care: there is still no Intel Linux graphic installer for Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm pretty sure this will work also on your PC.**

`Intel Graphics Driver` is a software that help you to install right Intel driver on your Ubuntu PC. This should make your Intel Graphic controller work properly. To install it follow these steps:

1. Download from [here](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/15.10/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.4.0-0intel1_amd64.deb) and save it where you want.
2. Open a terminal pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and change the current terminal working directory to where you downloaded the previous `.deb` file:

   ```
   cd <downloaded_file_location>
   ```
3. Install graphic installer with this command:

   ```
   dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.4.0-0intel1_amd64.deb
   ```

   If you want more information about `dpkg` command, type the following command to read the manual:

   ```
   man dpkg
   ```
4. Now Launch graphic `Intel graphic installer` and follow the instructions to install the software.
5. After driver installation close the program and reboot your system. When it start it should work on recommended resolution.

I hope this could help you.

---

More Intel software can be found here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Comment: The installed give me troubles because I have ubuntu 16.04, I fooled him making him think I have 15.10. But then I got troubles with the public keys :/