# unable to change refresh rate xrandr, x nvidia settings, gnome settings

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, framerate

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my laptop, which has an NVIDIA graphics card. However, I am unable to set a custom refresh rate for my monitor, which is capable of 100 Hz but is currently locked to 60.2 Hz.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. NVIDIA X Server Settings: I tried using the NVIDIA X Server Settings tool to set a custom refresh rate, but the "Attributes" section was not visible in the tool, even after enabling advanced settings.
2. xrandr: I tried using the xrandr command to add a new mode with a refresh rate of 100 Hz:

I ran `cvt 1920 1080 100` to calculate the stuff needed for my new refresh rate mode. this is what it returned:

```
# 1920x1080 99.90 Hz (CVT) hsync: 114.58 kHz; pclk: 302.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync
```

I then tried running

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync
```

but got the folllowing error:

```
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  37
```

I tried running `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 -hsync +vsync` but got:

```
xrandr: failed to parse '1920x1080_100.00' as a mode specification
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
```

I don't know what to do. I followed this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/59626/1664901
but nothing worked.

How do I know my monitor is capable of 100hz? I used 100hz on Micro**** Wind*ws for a long time and it worked.

In gnome settings there is only one option for the refresh rate: 60.2

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix it:

First you run `cvt 1920 1080 100` or whatever you want.
Then you get something like this:

```
# 1920x1080 99.90 Hz (CVT) hsync: 114.58 kHz; pclk: 302.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync
```

copy everything after modeline

then run:

```
xrandr --newmode MODELINE
```

then you can run `xrandr -q` and see that the new mode is somewhere in HDMI-1 or other disconnected monitor. That is intended.

Now run:

```
xrandr --addmode DISPLAY_NAME "1920_1080_100"
```

and then go into gnome settings and there you can select the new refresh rate. I hope answering my own question will help people in the future.